# Limit of sequence with one racing toward zero other toward infinity.

Tags: limits

I have problem with this. I can't find anything similar in books I have. I would be more glad for a good hint than for straightforward solution (but keep in mind I am not very gifted). Thank you for your time and help!

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} n\Bigg(\sqrt[k]{a^k + \frac{1}{n}} -\sqrt[k]{a^k - \frac{1}{n}} \Bigg)
$$

Comment: Are you sure about the parentheses? Currently it says $n(A - A) = 0$ for all $n$...

Comment: There probably is a typo, since as it is written the expression is identically $0$. Maybe the second term should be  $\sqrt[k]{a^k-\frac{1}{n}}$.

Comment: Maybe not.  Maybe idea was to *recognize* that each $ (\sqrt[k]{a^k + \frac{1}{n}} -\sqrt[k]{a^k + \frac{1}{n}}$ is equal to 0, the the question is really what  $\lim_{n \to \infty} 0$.  For a novice student, if presented as the difference of two limits heading to infinities in opposite directions directions, this isn't nescessarily trivial or obvious.

Comment: I've corrected it. Sorry for toruble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply through by $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \left( \sqrt[k]{a^k+\frac 1n} \right)^i \left( \sqrt[k]{a^k - \frac 1n} \right)^{k-1-i}$ and obtain
$$
n \left( \sqrt[k]{a^k+\frac 1n} - \sqrt[k]{a^k - \frac 1n} \right) \left( \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \left( \sqrt[k]{a^k+\frac 1n} \right)^i \left( \sqrt[k]{a^k - \frac 1n} \right)^{k-1-i} \right) \\
= n \left( \left( a^k + \frac 1n \right) - \left( a^k - \frac 1n \right) \right)  = 2
$$
using the $a^k-b^k$ identity (probably more well-known as the $a^n-b^n$ identity, but here $n$ is another symbol, so...). Since the factor we multiplied by converges to $k a^{k-1}$, the limit is equal to $2/(ka^{k-1})$.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $k$ is a constant, you are looking for
$f_k(n) = n\left( \sqrt[k]{a^k + \frac{1}{n}} -\sqrt[k]{a^k - \frac{1}{n}}\right)$ when $n\to\infty$.
You can start by factoring out:
$$
f_k(n) = n\left(\left( a^k + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{1/k} - \left(a^k - \frac{1}{n}\right)^{1/k}\right)
=an\left(  \left( 1 + \frac{1}{na^k} \right)^{1/k} - \left(1 - \frac{1}{na^k}\right)^{1/k} \right)
$$
by factoring out the $a^k$ in each term. And now you can expand both terms using the Taylor expansion
$$
(1+x)^\alpha = 1+\alpha x + o(x)
$$
when $x\to 0$, for any fixed $\alpha$.

Comment: Side note: André Nicolas's solution is more elegant, if you recognize the derivative (and uses simpler arguments). This answer is (slightly) heavier on the machinery used, namely Taylor expansions to first order (a.k.a. linear approximations to a function); but as the advantage of being systematic (i.e., it may not be always elegant or the fastest, but it will work in most situations).

Comment: I strongly agree that the Taylor expansion is the best tool, and in particular regret the common student enthusiam for L'Hospital's Rule. Unfortunately,  in calculus courses, the Taylor expansion often comes later than this kind of limit question.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Rewrite your expression as
$$\frac{\sqrt[k]{a^k+\frac{1}{n}}-a}{1/n}+\frac{\sqrt[k]{a^k+\frac{-1}{n}}-a}{-1/n}$$
and recognize the limit of each term as the derivative of $\sqrt[k]{x}$ at $x=a^k$.